# Two, locked, suggested edits?

Tags: bug, review, suggested-edits

When reviewing I managed to get stuck with two instances of the same review. I had previously skipped [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1359399). I then started to improve a second. I accidentally pressed backspace when not in the edit window.

I ended up with this:

[image: D'oh!]

None of the Approve/Reject/Skip buttons worked. Pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> brings up the *"You have started editing a post. Are you sure you want to re-load the page"* box, i.e. you have started editing a different post on a different page.

Steps to reproduce.

1. Wait 'till there's two edits in the queue.
2. Skip the first one.
3. Improve the second.
4. Click outside the edit window.
5. Press backspace.